# Postfix & Docevot & SASL: Dovecot timeback issue and smtpd&sasl crash help

Tags: postfix

Here is part of log from this night:

```
Aug 10 00:51:28 randevu dovecot: Time just moved backwards by 196 seconds. This might cause a lot of problems, so I'll just kill myself now. http://wiki.dovecot.org/TimeMovedBackwards
Aug 10 00:54:49 randevu postfix/smtpd[5411]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: Connection refused
Aug 10 00:54:49 randevu postfix/smtpd[5411]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Aug 10 00:54:50 randevu postfix/master[4517]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 5411 exit status 1
Aug 10 00:54:50 randevu postfix/master[4517]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Aug 10 00:55:46 randevu postfix/anvil[5355]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:70.38.100.6) at Aug 10 00:52:10
Aug 10 00:55:46 randevu postfix/anvil[5355]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:70.38.100.6) at Aug 10 00:52:10
Aug 10 00:55:46 randevu postfix/anvil[5355]: statistics: max cache size 2 at Aug 10 00:52:24
Aug 10 01:09:13 randevu postfix/smtpd[5528]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: Connection refused
Aug 10 01:09:13 randevu postfix/smtpd[5528]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Aug 10 01:09:14 randevu postfix/master[4517]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 5528 exit status 1
Aug 10 01:09:14 randevu postfix/master[4517]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Aug 10 01:10:14 randevu postfix/smtpd[5538]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: Connection refused
Aug 10 01:10:14 randevu postfix/smtpd[5538]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
Aug 10 01:10:15 randevu postfix/master[4517]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 5538 exit status 1
Aug 10 01:10:15 randevu postfix/master[4517]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Aug 10 01:11:15 randevu postfix/smtpd[5551]: warning: SASL: Connect to private/auth failed: Connection refused
Aug 10 01:11:15 randevu postfix/smtpd[5551]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms
```

Don't get it. How to fix this.

After system reboot at morning everything went back to normal. But how to prevent this in future?

I have read http://wiki.dovecot.org/TimeMovedBackwards and i have ntpd running on background.

Any tips would be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a physical or a virtual server?

Comment: it's virtual server

Comment: Then it is like the wiki says "a virtual server" issue (see under Bugs/Issues). Run the NTPD in the host and not the guest and let the guest synchronize the time with the host. NTPD _is not allowed in guests_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least VMware can be problematic with certain Linux kernel / distribution versions. Luckily they have [recommended options for several Linux flavours](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1006427) in their Knowledge Base. (I'm just lucky guessing you are using VMware).

Also operations performed at virtual host, such as snapshots, can cause all kind of troubles.

Comment: Using VirtualBox from Oracle and Ubuntu package from turnkey

Comment: @Janne thank you for the link. It's now in the Dovecot Wiki{1,2}, too.

Comment: @mailq: Oh, cheers! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Time drift within virtualized guests is common. The various "guest additions/utilities" aim to address that. In situations where there are no "guest additions/utilities" for an OS, then running regular time synchronizations/updates may be acceptable depending on the application

Answer (score 1):

If you have Virtualbox then the "time problem" maybe present there, too. Normally not, but who knows?
But fortunately Sun/Oracle provide information about how to handle this. http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#idp13754496

Keep in mind that this time jumps do come from virtualization and have to be fixed in the Host, the Guest and/or the Guest Additions.